# Read my Google Fit data via REST

Tags: c#, rest, google-api, gps, google-fit

I'd like to programmatically read my Google Fit GPS data via the REST API. I'm able to get a list of data sources but I just can't seem to get any session or dataset results back.

For example:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/sessions?oauth_token=mytoken
```

and:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/fitness/v1/users/me/dataset:aggregate?oauth_token=mytoken
{"aggregateBy": [{"dataTypeName": "com.google.location.sample"}]}
```

What am I missing? Is it even possible for my app to download data that it wasn't responsible for storing?

FWIW, I'm using the following [Google.Apis.Fitness.v1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Fitness.v1/) package test code in C#:

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "myid",
            ClientSecret = "mysecret"
        },
    new[]
        {
            FitnessService.Scope.FitnessLocationRead,
            FitnessService.Scope.FitnessActivityRead,
            FitnessService.Scope.FitnessBodyRead
        },
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None,
    new FileDataStore("google-fit.json", true));
var service = new FitnessService(
    new BaseClientService.Initializer {HttpClientInitializer = credential});
var dataSources = await service.Users.DataSources.List("me").ExecuteAsync();
var sessions = await service.Users.Sessions.List("me").ExecuteAsync();
var dataSets = await service.Users.Dataset.Aggregate(
    new AggregateRequest {AggregateBy = new[] {
        new AggregateBy {DataTypeName = "com.google.location.sample"}}}, "me")
    .ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: as far as I can see the FIT API doesn't release GPS location information.  Seriously I would be worried if it did we don't want random aps tracking us.  https://developers.google.com/fit/rest/v1/reference/

Comment: I don't see any problem with providing GPS data, so long as the user has explicitly granted the app access to it. I assume this is exactly what the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read` scope is for.

Comment: Yes but then the owner of the app can see where you are when ever they want not just when you are running their app. If that is OK with you then you are more trusting than I am.

Comment: What app are you using to insert GPS data?

Comment: I just want to access the GPS history that's captured by my Android phone. It has the Google Fit app installed but I rarely open it. According to https://www.google.com.au/maps/timeline and https://fit.google.com there's plenty of location information being stored against my Google account.